# Dropzone.js is not uploading images to folder

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I have been trying to make this dropzone.js work on a client's website and it doesn't seem to be working.

When I upload a file it doesn't upload to the photo folder and doesn't get added to the database.

The page to upload the files is in www.sunkyog.com/admin/dd.php [sample page I created], the PHP page is www.sunkyog.com/admin/up.php and the folder to upload to is www.sunkyog.com/photos.

This is my code:

**dd.php**

```
<head>   

<!-- 1 -->
<link href="css/dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- 2 -->
<script src="../js/dropzone.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<form action="http://sunkyog.com/admin/up.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="photoUploadDropzone"></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
Dropzone.options.photoUploadDropzone = {
  paramName: "file",
  maxFilesize: 5, // MB
  maxFiles: 10,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif",
  accept: function(file, done) {
    done();
  }
};
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**up.php**

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = "photos/";
$targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO club_photos VALUES('','photos/$tempFile','$fk_id')");
}
?>
```

You can go to the page http://www.sunkyog.com/admin/dd.php to try for yourself and then after uploading navigate to http://www.sunkyog.com/photos/yourFileName to see if it uploaded.

Comment: $targetPath = "http://sunkyog.com/photos/"; Is not correct. You need to fill in the path on the server and not the external HTTP path. probably this will be just "photos/". Also: make use of PDO instead of mysql_query. NEVER use mysql_* functions. At last: is that if triggering? Did you debug that if?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated it and its still not working. I know the sql is not up to par. am just trying for it to work even if its the basic way.

Comment: i checked the folder permission and its 0755 which can be writable.

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($_FILES);`?

Comment: nothing. And console doesn't show any error or warning

Comment: If anyone can suggest a better drag and drop upload with php, i would be grateful

Comment: Dropzone is actually pretty nice. I've a production site using it now, and the client was extremely happy with it. How many images are you trying to upload at once? In your console, can you inspect the `POST`?

Comment: max 50 or 100. But am just trying with 3 photos(7kb each). nothing shows at all. Is it that the post isn't reaching the up.php page? i have added the print_r($_FILES); to the page, you can try it out and check console, maybe am missing something

Comment: Since you have used it before, looking through my code any problems with it. except for the mysql

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="dropzone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
 var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#form_id");
  myDropzone.options.addRemoveLinks=true;
  myDropzone.options.uploadMultiple=false;
  myDropzone.options.autoProcessQueue=false;
  myDropzone.options.url='system_message_process.php';
  myDropzone.options.maxFiles=1;
   myDropzone.options.acceptedFiles='image/*';
  function submit(){
        myDropzone.processQueue();
         myDropzone.on("success", function(file,responsenew) {
                     // alert(responsenew);
                     var response = jQuery.parseJSON(responsenew);
              });
  }
 </script>
```

Please check it for submit manually or else set autodiscover as true also  processQueue as true and check once again along firebug request sent or not. its working fine for me

Comment: the id of the form should be "form-id". ok, i get you

Comment: it shows that it has uploaded one file band shows "you cannot upload more files" for the rest but still doesn't work

Comment: Did you check the firebug when you upload the file its request send or not?